# Should I install flannel on bare metal as systems service or run it as DaemonSet with k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

Trying to build k8s cluster on bare metal. I use CoreOS as host OS for my nodes. And I'm a bit confusing with the way I should install flannel for cluster networking.

I see from docs that I can either download it to my host machine and start it using `systemd` or use a [k8s DaemonSet manifest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml).

Personally I like the idea of DaemonSet because k8s will take care of running flannel on each node. But are there any disadvantages in running flannel as k8s-DaemonSet?

Documentation also says that I should run flannel before any other pods. That's why my first idea was to put it onto the path specified for kubelet `--pod-manifest` parameter. But since the yaml for flannel contains not `Pod` but `DaemonSet` and some RBAC-related entities I get the following error using `--pod-manifest` dir for deploying flannel:

> Can't process manifest file "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/flannel.yaml": /etc/kubernetes/manifests/flannel.yaml: couldn't parse as pod(invalid pod: &rbac.ClusterRole{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"flannel", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:v1.Time{Time:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}}, DeletionTimestamp:(*v1.Time)(nil), DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Initializers:(*v1.Initializers)(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:""}, Rules:[]rbac.PolicyRule{rbac.PolicyRule{Verbs:[]string{"get"}, APIGroups:[]string{""}, Resources:[]string{"pods"}, ResourceNames:[]string(nil), NonResourceURLs:[]string(nil)}, rbac.PolicyRule{Verbs:[]string{"list", "watch"}, APIGroups:[]string{""}, Resources:[]string{"nodes"}, ResourceNames:[]string(nil), NonResourceURLs:[]string(nil)}, rbac.PolicyRule{Verbs:[]string{"patch"}, APIGroups:[]string{""}, Resources:[]string{"nodes/status"}, ResourceNames:[]string(nil), NonResourceURLs:[]string(nil)}}, AggregationRule:(*rbac.AggregationRule)(nil)}), please check manifest file.

So if I want to execute my flannel yaml-manifest before other pods on particular node, where should I put it? Or the only option is to execute `kubectl apply -f flannel.yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That manifest includes a ClusterRole, a ClusterRoleBinding, a ConfigMap, and the DaemonSet resources (which implicitly defines the pod resources), so it can't be run with --pod-manifest, which only wants pod resource definitions.

I don't have comparative experience running flannel under systemd vs as a daemonset.

I would look at the AddOn manager as a way to ensure kubernetes objects are considered cluster services and are started early in cluster lifecycle:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager/README.md

Comment: Looks like add-on is the thing I was looking for. Just noticed that it's actually the way `kOVHernetes` project deploys `flannel` too.